When do arpeggiated intervals violate voice leading rules?

This is an elaboration of a falling 3rd progression where the 1st phrase takes very special care in the LH accompaniment to avoid parallel perfect intervals. The arpeggiation is expressed in such a way that each chord has different intervals from bass up. However, the second phrase is different. Here the intervals are repeated exactly from chord to chord for 3 bars. It sounds good to me and I can´t hear the parallels. How is this considered good voice leading while being an exact copy of bar to bar? Is it because of the 10th leap and then a descending arpeggio that makes it admissable? I can't hear the parallels so I am not sure if changing direction has something to do with it. Finally, if someone out there has something from the literature to help in understanding how figuration is dealt with in regard to arpeggiations it would be very helpful. From what I have seen, voice leading is still a consideration even when block chords are expressed as rolled chords or arpeggios.

"Rules" of voice leading are not absolute. They are guidelines that may need more strict or relaxed approach depending on the context (including the "style" of the piece). And, even though arpeggios are normally considered as block chords, the very fact that notes are not played together means that those rules can be less relevant. Remember that the common rules of voice leading developed from their namesake: voices; specifically, continuous musical "melodies" that were sung. Some rules exist because of tuning difficulty (most singers were/are not that good), others to highlight »

» the counterpoint, but most of them were "created" for a simple reason: simplicity; mostly performance easiness, but also listening, since a melody is easier to sing and listen (therefore, to "like") if it has many small intervals, as opposed to frequent "jumps". Progressions also allow some level of "rule bending". Then you have the fundamental aspect: it has to be good to hear. Considering all the above, you have: a progression (which leads to imitation), arpeggiated chords, and something that sounds good. Is it fine? Then you probably don't have to worry too much.
